# Adding Mongodb to ios project

Tags: cocoapods, mongodb-stitch

I am currently adding monogodb to my ios project. Just after following the instruction stitch mongodb offered, I am stuck at when pod installing StitchCoreSDK. It supposed to create a xcworkspace file, but it didn't. Instead, I got the following message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z2FR.jpg)

The podfile I create is like following

```html
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.4'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
target 'paotuaniOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  # Pods for paotuaniOS
  pod 'Nexmo-Stitch'
  pod 'StitchSDK', '~> 4.0.5'
  target 'paotuaniOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'paotuaniOSUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Can any one help me with this issue?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before.  The repo had problems. The repo has been updated. Please use

```
pod 'StitchSDK', '~> 4.1.1'
```